# How to save data using forms in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database

Hi I want to save data in Ruby On Rails using forms. But I want to give input like this:

[image: See the screen shot]

And when I save data it will display like regular data. How can I do this?

Mean I want to save a data in the forms of paragraphs, H1, H2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `html_safe` while showing the description like :-

`<%= obj.desc.html_safe %>`

https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe

Comment: But note that this is dangerous. If there is any page where a user can view HTML created by a different user, then the creating user can hack the account of the viewing user. To avoid this security problem you must first sanitize the HTML with a sanitization library such as [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize).